# reset two forms by one click JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have two forms .. each form has a reser button with the id called "formReset"
no all the form are showing in the same time, one shows after the other one

I used the below code but it only works on the first form, I can o it by doing two click buttons with different id's but is there a way to do it with one click only?

```js
document.getElementById("formReset").addEventListener("click",resetForm);

    function resetForm(){
        document.getElementById("login").reset();
        document.getElementById("cal").reset();
    }
```

```html
    <form id="login">
        <label>Enter your name : <span id="nameMsg"></span></label><br>
        <input type="text" id="name"><br>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" >
        <input type="button" id="formReset" value="reset" ><br>
    </form>
  
    <form id="cal">
    <input type="number" id="answer" ><br><br>
    <input type="button" id="submit2" value="submit2" >
    <input type="button" id="formReset" value="reset" >
    </form>
```

Comment: Element `id`s should be unique and not duplicated/used across different elements. Instead, you can use `class`, and use `getElementsByClassName` (or related method) which you can then loop through and add your event listener to

Answer (score 0):

Attribute [*id*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) should be unique in a document, use [*class*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) instead with [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) and [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) like the following way:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".formReset").forEach(function(reset){
  reset.addEventListener("click",resetForm);  
});
function resetForm(){
  document.getElementById("login").reset();
  document.getElementById("cal").reset();
}
```

```html
<form id="login">
  <label>Enter your name : <span id="nameMsg"></span></label><br>
  <input type="text" id="name"><br>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" >
  <input type="button" class="formReset" value="reset" ><br>
</form>

<form id="cal">
  <input type="number" id="answer" ><br><br>
  <input type="button" id="submit2" value="submit2" >
  <input type="button" class="formReset" value="reset" >
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".formReset").forEach(btn=>{
btn.addEventListener("click",resetForm)
});

function resetForm(e){
       e.target.parentElement.reset()

}
```

```html
<form id="login">
        <label>Enter your name : <span id="nameMsg"></span></label><br>
        <input type="text" id="name"><br>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" >
        <input type="button" class="formReset" value="reset" ><br>
    </form>
  
    <form id="cal">
    <input type="number" id="answer" ><br><br>
    <input type="button" id="submit2" value="submit2" >
    <input type="button" class="formReset" value="reset" >
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

easy way using closest.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".formReset").forEach(btn=>{
btn.addEventListener("click",resetForm)
});

function resetForm(e){
       e.target.closest('form').reset()

}
```

```html
<form id="login">
        <label>Enter your name : <span id="nameMsg"></span></label><br>
        <input type="text" id="name"><br>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" >
        <input type="button" class="formReset" value="reset" ><br>
    </form>
  
    <form id="cal">
    <input type="number" id="answer" ><br><br>
    <input type="button" id="submit2" value="submit2" >
    <input type="button" class="formReset" value="reset" >
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add click listeners for each reset button, then reset parent by click

.html

```
<form id="login">
<label>Enter your name : <span id="nameMsg"></span></label><br>
<input type="text" id="name"><br>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit">
<input type="button" class="formReset" value="reset"><br>
</form>

<form id="cal">
<input type="number" id="answer"><br><br>
<input type="button" id="submit2" value="submit2">
<input type="button" class="formReset" value="reset">
</form>
```

.js

```
document.querySelectorAll(".formReset").forEach((e) => {
    e.addEventListener("click", () => {
        document.querySelectorAll("form").forEach((f) => {
            f.reset();
        })
    });
});
```